# Accessing Hornetq Address setting in runtime

Tags: java, jms, messaging, hornetq

How to access the configured address setting properties via hornetq management api. I am using standalone hornetq sever. I would like to access the max-bytes-size setting in the address setting configuration in runtime. I see "AddressSettingInfo" class available in hornetq management package. Not sure how to query the management API to get AddressSettingInfo. Is it possible to get address settings via HornetQ Management API

Thanks in advance for your help.